# Jersey 3.0 not picking up NameBinding response filter

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey

I'm writing a Java web service in Eclipse using Jersey 3.0.2. I can see the json body fine in Postman. I need to add a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header but it's not coming through.

**Here is my base class:**

```
package net.codejava.ws;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/myhello")
public class HelloResource {
   
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @CORSFilterNameBinding
        public CelToFar getHelloJSON() {
            Logger log = Logger.getGlobal();
            log.severe("INSIDE HelloResource.getHelloJSON!");
            return new CelToFar();
        }
}
```

**I've got a name binding class:**

```
package net.codejava.ws;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import jakarta.ws.rs.NameBinding;

@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CORSFilterNameBinding {}
```

**And here's the filter class it refers to:**

```
package net.codejava.ws;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

@CORSFilterNameBinding
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
 
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {
 
            Logger log = Logger.getGlobal();
            log.severe("INSIDE FILTER!");
            responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            responseContext.getHeaders().add("X-Powered-By", "Jersey :-)");
    }
}
```

I'm seeing "INSIDE HelloResource.getHelloJSON!" in the Eclipse server console just fine but not seeing the log string for inside filter. I'm using the official docs (https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest3x/filters-and-interceptors.html) as my reference. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by adding the @Provider annotation. Note that the official docs (https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest3x/filters-and-interceptors.html) had nothing about this requirement.

```
package net.codejava.ws;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@CORSFilterNameBinding
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
 
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {
 
            Logger log = Logger.getGlobal();
            log.severe("INSIDE FILTER!");
            responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            responseContext.getHeaders().add("X-Powered-By", "Jersey :-)");
    }
}
```

Also, given that the package was listed as a provider in web.xml (and the filter class is in the package), you wouldn't think this was required anyway...:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>net.codejava.ws</param-value>
</init-param>
```

If anyone else knows why @Provider was required maybe leave a comment to help myself and other understand. Thanks